# Issue on Passing Multi Models to One View Based on the Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP.Net MVC,and EF I am trying to create an app which contains a Map and two buttons as marker loader based on their id and type of models

```
<a role="button" id="lib" class="btn btn-default">Add Libraries</a>
<a role="button" id="sch" class="btn btn-default">Add Schools</a>

<div id="map-box"></div>
```

inside the `homeController` I have

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public JsonResult GetSchools()
{
    using (GISEntities db = new GISEntities())
    {
        var schools = db.Points.Where(s => s.type == "school").ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = schools, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}

public JsonResult GetLibraries()
{
    using (GISEntities db = new GISEntities())
    {
        var schools = db.Points.Where(s => s.type == "library").ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = schools, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

now I can not figure it out how to pass the model from the controller into the view based on each click request, as I think we can only pass one model into the view! if so how can I update the map contents using MVC framework? 
Please be inform that I do not want to update the entire map by creating a partial class or partial view! what I need is only passing different model to view based on the request.

Comment: The model is used to populate the view on the server side.  What I understand you're wanting to do will need to be done via javascript.